# CKEditor 4: Can't move cursor outside of table in Firefox

Tags: firefox, html-table, ckeditor, cursor

In CKEditor 4.3, if I've added a table to an empty editor in Firefox, I can't get my cursor below the table whether I try mouse clicking or various keyboard keys like arrows and enter.

Quick steps to reproduce:

- Use Firefox
- Go to ckeditor.com/demo
- In the Standard Editor, hit the Source button and enter this:

  ```
  <table border="1" style="width:100px">
  <tbody>
  <tr><td></td></tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
  ```
- Switch back to wysiwyg mode (toggle off the Source button)
- Try to get your cursor below the existing table using arrows, typing, or mouse clicks. For that matter try to get the cursor above the table.

Note that I could theoretically use the magicline plug-in to accomplish this, but would have to think there is another way. Chrome handles using the arrow keys or mouse click to exit the table, but it's impossible to do with Firefox.

Comment: That's exactly why magicline was implemented. Because sometimes there's no other way.

Answer (score 0):

Place < then br then /> line break tag after the table tag in source mode
Change back from source mode and place cursor below table.